# storing result of a function that loops through my classes not working

Tags: javascript

Whenever I create a function like this and run the function directly it works but why cant I store my classLoop call? I want to store the elements it finds but it keeps return NULL. This should have behaved similar to jquery's `var x = $('.foo')`

What could the reason be?

```
 function classLoop (elem){
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        elem[i];
    };
}
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
var items = classLoop(x);
console.log(items)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4jcph92s/5/

**EDIT:** Sorry wanted to update this real fast for you guys and forgot to add the "document." part.

Comment: What are you returning? Nothing. It should be undefined and not null.

Comment: You might want to [take a read of this](http://dfsq.info/site/read/writing-your-own-jquery), or perhaps just look at [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: @epascarello edited. Sorry forgot to feed in the actual element to loop

Comment: So, now your updated fiddle works - what's the method supposed to do? Just return out the same list as you pass in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it doesn't return null it returns `undefined` (to be exact) because you're never actually *returning* anything from your method. You do this with the `return` keyword.

```
function myFunc(){
    return "Hello World"
}
```

Aside from that, your method does not do what you think it's going to do. You pass the string `foo`, which I can see from your fiddle you have an element with that class, but you're iterating over the literal string "foo" not the elements with the class "foo".

I think perhaps what you were trying to do is something along the lines of

```
function classLoop (elem){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(elem)
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        arr.push(elements[i])
    };
    return arr;
}
```

But thats just a *very* long winded way of writing:

```
function classLoop (elem){
    return document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
}
```

Which is clearly pointless - but as I have no idea what you're trying to do the above demonstrates a few ideas.

Comment: edited. Sorry forgot to feed in the actual element to loop

Comment: edited my question. I forgot to add a few things in my sample code. document.getElementsByClassName returns an html collection which I cant really manipulate so I need to loop through them first

Comment: Absolutely awesome idea. I never had any use for push until now so now I know : )

Comment: I have no idea what your method is trying to do, so this is about the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: well it is supposed to replace jquerys way of getting classes

Comment: then look up `querySelectorAll` - dont write this yourself!

Comment: *"Well it returns null (actually: undefined to be exact)"* It doesn't return null in any way, shape, or form. It returns undefined. The answer shouldn't start by saying something that simply isn't true.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I parroted the OP. And did you read the bit in brackets?

Comment: @Jamiec: Yes, I did -- and the question. I'm saying that the rhetorical device is not useful (pretty much at all), and certainly not useful enough to echo a statement which is quite simply wrong. :-)

Comment: I think I need to store the arr object outside of the loop , otherwise I cant get the data from console.log() or whatever im trying to do

Answer (score -1):

you got to use `document.getElementsByClassName`

```
  function classLoop (elem){


         var count=[];
    var element=document.getElementsByClassName(elem);
            for (var i = 0; i <  element.length; i++) {
                count.push(element[0])
            };
            return count
        }

        var items = classLoop('foo');
    console.log(items)
```

Comment: edited. Sorry forgot to feed in the actual element to loop

Comment: calling `document.getElementsByClassName` repeatedly is a bad bad idea. Its called each iteration as part of the loop control and again inside each iteration. Thats twice per element on the page with that class name :|

Comment: @user1386579 shouldnt we store the stuff within a variable first? You didnt cache the element

Comment: @Asperger I dont see a point in dooing it outside or inside the function